# Using concat, coalesce, sum and format in one statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a `FORMAT` to my query, but when I run my query I get an error.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('€ ', COALESCE(SUM(r), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(l), 0)) as totaal 
  FROM trans 
 WHERE user_id = 1
   AND k_id= 110
 GROUP 
    BY user_id 
 LIMIT 0,1
```

I tried multiple statements:

`(FORMAT(r)) and (FORMAT(l))` gives error

`FORMAT(SUM(r), 0) - FORMAT(SUM(l), 0)` gives wrong response

`CONCAT(FORMAT('€ ', COALESCE(SUM(r), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(l), 0)))` gives error

`FORMAT(CONCAT('€ ', COALESCE(SUM(r), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(l), 0)))` gives also error

Can someone help me with this statement?

Comment: "I get an error" is not a helpful statement. Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. GROUP BY won't guarantee the order.

Answer (score 1):

`format(X,D)` takes a number as the first parameter and the decimal places as the second parameter so it should be put where the result is a number and provided with a number of decimal places:

```
 CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(COALESCE(SUM(r), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(l), 0),0))
```